# Python invalid syntax when using eval(strClass)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, eval, classname

I have a list of class names as strings, and if I say fe. `print(cNames[0])` it will result into `Foo` since `cNames[0] = "Foo"`. Now if I wanted to compare a class string with a class, I would do this:

```
if eval(cNames[0]) in classes:
    foo = eval(cNames[0])()
```

How ever, it's giving me invalid syntax error:

```
  File ".\testing.py", line 54, in convert
    print("Class: %s" %eval(cNames[0]))
  File "<string>", line 1
    <class 'testing.Foo'>
    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I know I'm only printing the class name, but it didn't work for if sentence either, so I tried to do it with a print. No effect

**EDIT:**
So the problem appeared to be me calling `eval("<class 'testing.Foo'>")` instead of `eval("Foo")`. Now this leads into few problems, I'm working with sqlite3 database and I'm trying to save a string as following: `<class>:i` for example `Foo:53`, but instead I'm doing `<class 'testing.Foo'>:53`, and that's why calling eval on it wouldn't work. How could I turn `<class 'testing.Foo'>` (not a string, the class itself) into string "Foo"?

Comment: ``eval()`` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: can't you do it with `getattr(globals(), cNames[0])`?

Comment: Why's that? How should I compare class string with a class then?

Comment: also, is this py3? you use print as a function, not a statement

Comment: If you have a list of class names as strings, `cNames[0] in classes` should work.

Comment: It obviously is py3. I tried doing `if getattr(classes, cNames[0]):` and I got this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '<class 'testing.Foo'>'`

Comment: @Mahi so you don't have a list of class names, but a list of their string representations.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I have a list of classes called `classes` and then I have a list of class names as strings called `cNames[0]`

Comment: @Mahi Print ``cNames`` - it's not what you think it is. It appears to be ``['<class 'testing.Foo'>', ...]``.

Comment: @Mahi "testing.Foo" != "<class 'testing.Foo'>". Only the first one is useful.

Comment: Can you post the full code please? Also, you can't use gettattr on lists, because the objects they store are not their attributes. You can use L[L.index(obj)] or something as alternative

Comment: I've updated the main post :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list containing your classes, you can do this quite tidily without using `eval`

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Thing(object):
    pass

# List of interesting classes
classes = [Foo, Thing]

# Construct a dictionary where the key is the Classes __name__ attribute
classByNames = {cls.__name__:cls for cls in classes}

# Example usage
cName = 'Foo'
if cName in classByNames:
    inst = classByNames[cName]()
    print(inst) # <__main__.Foo object at ...>
else:
    print("Unknown class %s" % cName)
```

(only tested the above in Python v2.7, but should work fine in v3 also)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure what is happening here is you are doing the `eval()` twice - and that `cNames[0]` is the representation you get of the class when you print it. That is, you are doing:

```
eval("<class 'testing.Foo'>")
```

I will say, however, this is a bad way of doing it. Store a dictionary which goes from name to class and use that - it's the clearer, more reliable, safer, faster method (you can generate this dictionary if you really feel it's needed).

Comment: You should do the `eval` not even once.

Comment: Of course - my first comment on the question was saying that, but I'm explaining why it doesn't work - whether it's a terrible idea or not.